# Can someone help me understand what is wrong with my code?

Tags: html, css

I created a scrolling function on the Homepage of the website I've created, but when I deploy, using GITHUB, the images don't appear.  If you open the below link on a laptop or desktop, you will be able to see little lines moving across the screen, which should be images.  My code even includes s little description of the link, which if you hover over the section, you will be able to see.  The links work if you click them, opening the webpage in a new window, but not sure why the images appear when I open in the browser

The images scroll across the page correctly when opening from Visual Studio and also deploying directly from GitHub
https://aka1973.github.io/AmerKorAsian/HomePage.html

but when I open the Homepage from the actual website, https://www.amerkorasian.com/homepage
, the images are no longer visible.

The below code is one of the sections that is part of the code.

```html
            <div class="slide">
                <a href="https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="../AmerKorAsian/images/Finance News Websites/bloomberg2.jpg"/>
                <div class="image__overlay">
                    <a href="https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/" style="text-decoration:none" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Provides in-depth coverage of global financial markets for finance professionals.</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[Bloomberg Google Stock Image]Thank you in advance for helping.

Regards:

Ryan Holland

Comment: Did you check your console about if your code doesn't throw any error? Or have the enough time gone after deploying the website?

Comment: Maybe you should use absolute addressing (src of images) for the actual website.

Comment: Thank you Armin.  Have just updated 2 of the links, but your suggestion worked perfectly.